# HTML5 canvas frameworks and tools

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I'm starting a new project that will use **HTML5** and HTML5 **canvas**.

The project is basically an interactive 2D diagram that will show some objects in the screen, you can click the objects, make some actions over the objects, I need zoom and translate features, and also drag and drop support.

1. What **frameworks** (maybe something similar to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)) are available to make the work easier?
2. What **tools** (debuggers, editors and so one) do you think are better to improve the productivity?

Comment: Will you please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve....? That might help others, *help* you in a better manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lime.js is a nice framework for such things. It has great documentation, very straight forward codes, examples with commented functionality and (since you asked this specifically) drag and drop support. It's usually used for games but you can easily use it for something that you're after as well.

You can find everything about lime.js here: http://www.limejs.com/

As for tools, I just use Sublime Text 2 for editing and debugg using the Chrome Developer tool.